# Issue with Memoization in Recursive Function for Finding Combinations Summing to Target

Tags: python, recursion, dynamic-programming, memoization

I need to write the following function:

> **Write a function that takes in a target `(int)` and a list of `int`s. The function should return a list of any combination of elements that add up to the target, if there is no combination that adds up to target return `None`.**

This is my initial solution using recursion:

```py
def how_sum(target: int, nums: list[int]) -> list[int] | None:
    if target == 0: return []
    if target < 0: return None

    for num in nums:
        remainder = target - num
        rv = how_sum(remainder, nums)
        
        if rv is not None:
            return rv + [num]

    return None
```

Then I tried to reduce the time complexity and make my code efficient even for large numbers:

```py
def how_sum(target: int, nums: list[int], memo: dict[int, list[int]] = {}) -> list[int] | None:
    if target in memo: return memo[target]
    if target == 0: return []
    if target < 0: return None

    for num in nums:
        remainder = target - num
        rv = how_sum(remainder, nums, memo)

        if rv is not None:
            memo[target] = rv + [num] # Note: if I comment this line everything works fine!
            return rv + [num]

    memo[target] = None
    return None


def main():
    print(how_sum(7, [2, 3]))  # [3, 2, 2]
    print(how_sum(7, [5, 3, 4, 7]))  # [3, 2, 2]
    print(how_sum(7, [2, 4]))  # [3, 2, 2]
    print(how_sum(8, [2, 3, 5]))  # [2, 2, 2, 2]
    print(how_sum(500, [7, 14]))  # [3, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, ..., 7]


main()
```

As you can see in the comments it returns the wrong output.

These are the correct output:

```py
def main():
    print(how_sum(7, [2, 3]))  # [3, 2, 2]
    print(how_sum(7, [5, 3, 4, 7]))  # [4, 3]
    print(how_sum(7, [2, 4]))  # None
    print(how_sum(8, [2, 3, 5]))  # None
    print(how_sum(500, [7, 14]))  # None
```

When I comment this line `memo[target] = rv + [num]` everything works fine but I can't figure out why it doesn't work if I leave it as it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues I see with this code.  First your claim about the correct solution to this input:

```
print(how_sum(8, [2, 3, 5]))  # None
```

seems incorrect.  Given the explanation, either `[3, 5]` or `[2, 2, 2, 2]` are valid answers.  Similarly for:

```
 print(how_sum(7, [5, 3, 4, 7]))  # [4, 3]
```

where `[7]` is also a valid result.  As far as your code issue, the problem is a common one in that you're using a dangerous default value in a situation where it isn't warranted:

```
def how_sum(target, nums, memo={})
```

Since `nums` is different between top level calls, the `memo` cache has to be reinitialized at the start of each recursion stack.  Otherwise, you have results in it from a previous run where `nums` was different.  One possible approach:

```
def how_sum(target: int, nums: list[int], memo: dict[int, list[int]] = None) -> list[int] | None:
    if memo is None:
        memo = {0: []}

    if target not in memo:
        memo[target] = None

        if target > 0:
            for num in nums:
                remainder = target - num
                rv = how_sum(remainder, nums, memo)

                if rv is not None:
                    memo[target] = [*rv, num]
                    break

    return memo[target]
```